# Cannot pass a list from the controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass a list of values from the controller to the view, but apparently I got this issue where the list cannot be passed. I already tried passing one value and it has no problem. But when I try to pass list, it show the following error -

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[vidly.Models.pelanggan]', but this
> dictionary requires a model item of type 'vidly.models.pelanggan'.

I have this model -

```
public class pelanggan
{
    public string Nama { get; set; }
}
```

The controller code -

```
// GET: Pelanggan
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var name = new List<pelanggan> {
       new pelanggan {Nama = "Paidi" },
       new pelanggan {Nama = "Budi" }
    };

    return View(name);
}
```

This is my view file

```
@model vidly.Models.pelanggan

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Customer</h2>

@foreach(var Nama in Model.pelanggan)
{
   <li>@Nama.Nama</li>
}
```

I already tried to create a `ViewModel` but it also showing same error. Can you point where the error is?

Comment: you are passing a `List<pelanggan>` to your view but there your model specifies a single instance of  `vidly.Models.pelanggan` ...

Comment: how to passing a 'List<pelanggan>' to view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the missmatch of types between what you return `return View(name);` and what te view expects `@model vidly.Models.pelanggan` You could change to `@model List<vidly.Models.pelanggan>` but instead I'd say:

```
    public class pelanggan
    {
        public List<string> Namas { get; set; }

    }
```

Then

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new pelanggan {
             name = new List<string> {
                         "Paidi",
                         "Budi" 
                    }
              };

            return View(model);
        }
```

And finally in your view

```
       @foreach(var Nama in Model.Namas)
       {
           <li>@Nama</li>
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a `List<T>` from the controller. So, the model declared in your view should be able to receive a list and iterate over it.

Replace the model declaration in the view file with following -

```
@using vidly.Models;
@model IEnumerable<pelanggan>
```

Then you can iterate/loop over the model like -

```
@foreach(var p in Model)  // p represents a "pelanggan" object in the list 
{
   <li>@p.Nama</li>
}
```

Comment: How to print it to view, i tried @foreach (var Nama in Models.pelanggan) it showing error

Comment: @omik919 Updated the answer.

Comment: oh i see, its worked, but i have question whats the difference @foreach(var p in Model) and foreach(var p in Models.pelanggan), i tried foreach(var p in Models.pelanggan) but it show some error, why foreach(var p in Models.pelanggan) does not worked?

Comment: @omik919, In the first case, `Model` itself is a list, and in the second case `Model` is an object of some class that has property named `pelanggan` which is a list.

Comment: @omik919 In our case in the answer, we declared the model variable as `@model IEnumerable<vidly.Models.pelanggan>` which makes the type of `Model` a list of `pelanggan` object. So, it can now receive/hold the list of `pelanggan` object returned from the controller.

Comment: @omik919 Don't confuse or mix-up the `Model` in the `foreach` loop with `Models` in the model variable declaration. The `Models` in the declaration is just a part of a namespace for the `pelanggan` class.

Comment: @omik919 I've updated the model declaration code. It will make more sense now.